# Does the area under the curve remain the same in this variable transformation?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, derivatives

$X$ is a continuous random variable with probability density function $f(X)$. Let $Y = f(X)$. Let $g(.)$ be the pdf of $Y$. Intuitively I think below relation holds true, how to prove it does or doesn't, under what conditions?

$\int_0^{y_1}g(y)dy = \int_Rf(x)dx$

where $R={x:f(x)<y_1}$

Only thing I could do was to note that $y=f(x)$ hence $dy = df(x) = ?$

Any hints?

Comment: I suspect that you want two different $f$'s; one for the probability density of $X$, and another for the transformation $Y = f(X)$.

Comment: @Tunococ yes, $g$ is the pdf of $Y$ and $f$ is the pdf of $X$

Comment: I meant to say that you might not want $Y = f(X)$ with the same $f$ as the pdf of $X$. (It is possible that you want the same $f$, but it is quite unlikely because in general, a pdf is not one-to-one.)

Comment: @Tunococ Actually, I do want Y = f(X) where f is the pdf of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you can write is $P(Y<y_1) = P(f(X) < y_1)$ and, being $g_Y$ and $g_X$ the pdf of $Y$ and $X$ respectively, you have
$$
\int_0^{y_1}g_Y(y)dy = \int_F g_X(x)dx,
$$ 
with $F := \{x : f(x) < y_1\}$.

When, $f \equiv g_X$, you have the equation you were looking for.